# Angular-Translate with custom filter

Tags: angularjs, filter, translate, angular-translate

How can I use my own custom filter to format lets say, day in week to be not Sunday, Monday... but to use my `$translate` service. For Example

```
app.filter('formatDate', ['$translate', function ($translate) {
return function (date) {
    var now = new Date();
    var date = new Date(date);
    var monthNames = [
        "Jan", "Feb", "March",
        "Apr", "May", "June", "July",
        "Aug", "Sept", "Oct",
        "Nov", "Dec"
    ];
    dayNames = [
    "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
    ];

    var formattedDate;
    ...
    ...

    if (now.getDate() == date.getDate() && now.getMonth() == date.getMonth() && now.getFullYear() == date.getFullYear()) {
        if (diffSeconds < 120) {
            formattedDate = 'few seconds ago';
        }
        else {
            if (diffSeconds <= 300) {
                formattedDate = Math.round(diffSeconds / 60) + ' minutes ago';
            }
            else {
                formattedDate ='at '+hours + ':' + minutes + ampm;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if(diffDays == 1)
            formattedDate = 'yesterday';
        else {
            if (diffDays < 7){
                formattedDate = 'on ' + dayNames[date.getDay()];
            }
            else{
                formattedDate = monthNames[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getDate() + ', ' + date.getFullYear();
                }
            }
        }

    return formattedDate;
};
}]);
```

How can I have the array dayNames to use my translated days in weeks?

Comment: Use [$translate.instant()](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate#methods_instant).

Comment: Did you know you can provide translations to angulars built in date filter? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n . Here's the english bundle: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngLocale/angular-locale_en-gb.js

Comment: No... not familiar with it... I'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: @JBNizet $translate.instant() worked! you may wanna add it as an answer? as it is the right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `$translate.instant()` to solve this...

```
dayNames = [
    $translate.instant("Sunday"), 
    $translate.instant("Monday"), 
    $translate.instant("Tuesday"), 
    $translate.instant("Wednesday"), 
    $translate.instant("Thursday"), 
    $translate.instant("Friday"), 
    $translate.instant("Saturday")
];
```